# Извлечение domain из url

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Мой код:

```
import re
domain = re.match('\/\/(.*?)\/', 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions')
print(domain)
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
ru.stackoverflow.com
```

Печатает None, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Пример: https://regex101.com/r/j0G7vc/1 - попробуйте так `(?<=:\/\/)[^\/]+` вытащит весь текст от `://` до  первого `/`

Comment: тоже None, мой пример тоже работает в конструкторе, но что-то с синтаксисом видимо не правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из описания функции `match`: "Try to apply the pattern at the **start of the string**". Он ищет совпадение **с начала строки**. Вот так уже ищется, если указать, что до вашего шаблона могут быть произвольные символы:

```
domain = re.match('.*\/\/(.*?)\/', 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions')
                   ^^
```

Вывод:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 29), match='https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'>
```

Ну или используйте `findall`:

```
domain = re.findall('\/\/(.*?)\/', 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions')
```

Вывод:

```
['ru.stackoverflow.com']
```

А вообще `URL`-и нужно парсить специальными библиотеками, уж больно много там особенностей может быть, все их довольно сложно предусмотреть:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

print(urlparse('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions'))
```

Вывод:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='ru.stackoverflow.com', path='/questions', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.   
 'А вообще URL-и нужно парсить специальными библиотеками, уж больно много там особенностей может быть' - я файлы с куками подписываю, домен в качестве имени беру, думаю в моем случае так сойдет))

Comment: @Alexandr Ну, лучше сразу приучаться делать правильно. А то потом будете копипастить по привычке старый код, а он в новых условиях может и неправильно работать %)